# Use Jenkins to deploy WAR file and restart application server

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins

I am trying to deploy an application WAR file using Jenkins ANT to build the WAR and restart the server.

Once the WAR is built, I have written a shell script to stop the application server, deploy the WAR file and then restart the application server.

```
#Shutdown Tomcat
ssh tomcat@<servername>  "cd /home/tomcat/app/bin/;exec bash ./shutdown.sh"
#waiting period
ssh tomcat@<servername>  "sleep 10"

ssh tomcat@<servername>  "cd /home/tomcat/app/webapps/;rm -r *"
#Copy the WAR file to webapps
#Start the tomcat server
ssh tomcat@<servername>  "cd /home/tomcat/app/bin/;exec bash ./startup.sh"
```

It does shutdown the server, clear some temporary files but fails  to start the tomcat server. Any idea why this would be happening?

I have tried to see if there are other processes or ports still in use guessing maybe the shutdown was not clean. However there doesnt seem to be any issue like that. When I manually start the tomcat server for the application by going to the tomcat/bin directory, Tomcat starts without any issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure that bash is installed on the tomcat server, could it be failing because it doesn't exist?  is it necessary to change to the bin directory before starting it or could you just fully-qualify the command to run the script?  also not sure why you need to exec bash the startup.sh call.

Comment: @ScottSosna yes bash is installed. It is able to do a shutdown. So that command does work. It simply doesnt start the server on the startup command.

Comment: anything in the Tomcat logs?

Comment: @ScottSosna, nope clean as whistle!